# how to use whether and whether or not

Tags: grammar

Should I write ...

> ... **whether or not** any decisions have been made moving forward on that position ...

or

> ... **whether** any decisions have been made moving forward on that position ...

?

Comment: Do you have the rest of the sentence? Because that will make a big difference to the answer

Answer (score -1):

Whether is a conjuction(or this or that), so when using you should present at least two options.

So you should write whether this decision is taken or not.

But I would go with ...aside from any decision taken...